# SpriteKit: How to react on position changes by physics simulation

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics

I setup physics simulation in a SpriteKit project, having colliding bodies on nodes, also containing sprites. This part works flawlessly so far. Anyway, as I want to rotate my sprites according the movement direction, I wan to react on position changes on the sprite nodes, when objects collide.

Therefore, I overwrote the position var in my SKNode inherited class holding the bodies and sprites. But this handler is only called at the beginning, where I set initial position by code myself. It is not called, when the node moves due to physic bodies collision.

Guess, I'm getting something wrong in my understandings on how physics change node properties, but didn't find something pointing me to the right direction by research.

Comment: Have you looked at [SKConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKConstraint) in iOS8? One thing you can do with it is use it to force a node to be oriented in a certain direction before each frame is rendered.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to limit something, just beeing informed about the position change of my node, according the physics and forces that apply.

Comment: How do you want your sprites to rotate based on direction and collisions? Do you want them to face in the direction they are moving?

Comment: Hi, yes. Thats why I want to get informed of position changes by physics.